# Cannot install new QGIS 3.16 'Hannover' on Mint 20.1 'Ulyssa'

Tags: qgis, installation, linux-mint

I have tried to install the latest release version of QGIS (as per today, 3.16) on Mint 20.1 using the same steps from the QGIS page:

```
sudo apt install gnupg software-properties-common
wget -qO - https://qgis.org/downloads/qgis-2020.gpg.key | sudo gpg --no-default-keyring --keyring gnupg-ring:/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/qgis-archive.gpg --import

sudo chmod a+r /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/qgis-archive.gpg
sudo add-apt-repository 'deb https://qgis.org/debian focal main'
sudo apt update
sudo apt install qgis qgis-plugin-grass
```

However, the system installed QGIS 3.10.4 (an old version), which is the same version available on the software manager.
I have tried to change the repo link to (https://qgis.org/ubuntu) and still did not install the correct version.

Any reason why this is happening?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Background

Linux Mint 20.1 (Ulyssa) is based on the Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS (Focal Fossa), Therefore directing to the ubuntu repositories will fix the problem instead of debian.

### Answer

go to the **software sources** of the **Mint Ulyssa**

[image]

### Method 1

please try to find the following line in **additional repositories**

```
deb https://qgis.org/debian Ulyana main
```

or

```
deb https://qgis.org/debian focal main
```

then try to add the original ubuntu reference sources `focal` instead of the `Ulyaana` and `ubuntu` instead of the `debian` like as follows,

```
deb https://qgis.org/ubuntu focal main
```

then try to upgrade existing one,

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

or install QGIS if you don have it already installed,

```
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install qgis qgis-plugin-grass
```

in short,
change the repo link to ubuntu repo `deb https://qgis.org/ubuntu focal main`

### Method 2

please try to find the following line in **additional repositories** then try to add the original ubuntu reference sources to the **additional repositories**

```
deb     https://qgis.org/ubuntu focal main
deb-src https://qgis.org/ubuntu focal main
```

and delete all other old repositories on QGIS with in **additional repositories** if any,

then try to upgrade existing one,

```
sudo apt-get update
sudi apt-get upgrade
```

or install QGIS if you don have it already installed,

```
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install qgis qgis-plugin-grass
```

### Additional Note

when you are upgrading you can use `-a` to upgrade all with packages which are halted from upgrading with the use of the code,

```
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get upgrade -a
```

Answer (score 0):

Same problem over here while trying to install 3.22.2-Białowieża on Linux Mint 20.3 'Una'. I had to add the 'nightly build' repository to the /etc/apt/sources.list. This way it worked. Thanks for the tip.

[image]

[image]

[image]